# Twitter Bootstrap: Button dropdowns and list group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Take a look at the fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/pouya314/bzdK5/

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x pull-right"></i>
      item1
      <!-- Single button -->
      <span class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
      </span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x pull-right"></i>
      item2
  </a>
</div>

<span class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
  </span>
```

When I place a button dropdown "inside" a list group, it stops dropping down! Whereas, on its own (notice the exact same button drop down below the list) it works as expected.

I cannot figure out why and how to get around it.

Comment: Here is more proper fiddle for your example: [http://jsfiddle.net/k4bGY/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/k4bGY/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You must remove `<a>` element from list.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/bzdK5/3/

```
    <div class="list-group">
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
items1 <span class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </span>
        </li> <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
      item2
  </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: but I need the list group to have "Linked" items. that's a requirement.

Comment: Use an onclick event instead

Answer (score 1):

if you are use "div" tag instead of "a" tag as per below code, it's work properly

```
<div class="list-group">


    <div class="list-group-item">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x pull-right"></i>
          item1
          <!-- Single button -->
          <span class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  Action <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
          </span>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x pull-right"></i>
          item2
      </a>
    </div>

    <span class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
      </span>
```

Comment: but I need the list group to have "Linked" items. that's a requirement.